# Find the percentage of games "Snakes and Ladders" that can be completed after each round

Tags: probability, markov-chains

[This](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/november12011/) article has the following graph in it:

[image]

I can understand how to achieve the cumulative probability of finishing the game in $N$ moves. I implemented it by finding the probability matrix $P$ and initializing a vector $u$ with all zeros except the first element. Then by successively applying $u = uP$ for let's say a hundred moves and plotting $u_{100}$ from each move arriving at this plot:

[image]

How can I come up with the first plot, namely the chance of winning a game in $N$ moves?

Comment: If you can find the second plot - that is, if you can find $P_{cum}(n)$ - then the value in the first plot $P_{exact}(n)$ is just $P_{cum}(n)-P_{cum}(n-1)$: the probability that the game is done this turn, minus the probability that it was done last turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to play 10,000 games and keep track of the results.  Or, program a computer to play 1 million games.  This technique is called Monte Carlo simulation.  While the results may be aproximate, if you run enough scenarios it looks pretty good.

Annother approach is a Markov chain.  You build a matrix, that tells you that for the current location of your token, what is the probability on your next roll being in each other location.

$A^n$ tells the probability that your token will be an any other location after n rolls.

and of the game being over after $n$ rolls.